# My question is about Google sheet looping through a range of cells and ranking scores

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

[image]

Embedded is an image of what I need to do for some teachers in the school system I work in. Column A has the scores, and in column B I need to be able to rank the scores. The rank number starts at 1 and should stay the same until there is a change in the score value and then it should increment by one. I know I need some sort of looping structure, but I don't know how to do that in Google Sheets or google application script. Does someone know how to do this using a loop?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function scoreRanking() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rObj={};
  var s=1;//Initial rank value
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(rObj.hasOwnProperty([vA[i][0]])) {
      vA[i][1]=rObj[vA[i][0]];

    }else{
      rObj[vA[i][0]]=s++;
      vA[i][1]=rObj[vA[i][0]];
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

- [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much. I can learn from this code too. Again, many thanks!!!